# Is there any evidence of Dr. Zakir Naik paying people to convert to Islam?

Tags: islam, india

[India Today](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/india-today-investigation-zakir-naik-islamic-research-foundation/1/724629.html) wrote in [this](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/india-today-investigation-zakir-naik-islamic-research-foundation/1/724629.html) article:

> During their conversation with the SIT, Mufti made startling claims that Dr Naik extended benefits to converts. **"They were formally paid and got converted,"** the cleric alleged when a reporter asked whether a number of Hindus had indeed changed their belief after listening to Dr Naik's speeches. "He (the televangelist) gives benefits. He gives a lot of benefits. Not just like that," Khan added. "If one converts, he gives a lot of support. He helps them stand in the community," the businessman continued. In his claims, Mufti also alleged Saudi funding behind Dr Naik's proselytising programs. "Especially if Saudi Arabia is funding, they (the Saudis) would get to know he's doing that work for them, making non-Muslims accept Islam. If he doesn't do that, his funding from there will stop," the religious leader said.

Is there any evidence of Dr. Zakir Naik paying people to convert to Islam?

Answer (score 17):

A Mumbai police report found that Zakir Naik's Islamic Research Foundation (IRF):

> lured the youth to convert to Islam by paying them anything between Rs. 25,000 and Rs. 50,000

Source: [Zakir Naik's IRF paid Rs 25,000 to Rs 50,000 to lure youth to convert to Islam: Mumbai Police report](http://www.ibtimes.co.in/zakir-naiks-irf-paid-rs-25000-rs-50000-lure-youth-convert-islam-mumbai-police-report-689513) International Business Times 10 August 2016

However, since the complete police report is not publicly available at this time, it is not possible to evaluate the nature of the evidence against him.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Do you have anything to corroborate your dispute?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg He supports the **mainstream salafi movement which is currently at war with Daesh.** The claim simply doesn't make any sense. It's based on a dead report which says Dhaka attackers followed him on social media.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin-It is also alleged that terror suspects such as  Mohammad Ibrahim Yazdani, Najibullah Zazi, Kafeel Ahmed were inspired by Dr. Zakir Naik-http://www.theweek.in/news/india/zakir-naik-preacher-disliked-by-muslims-inspired-these-terrorists.html. Is that untrue? You can also inspired to form a question on this too-http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/dr-zakir-naik-dhaka-attack-terrorists-isis-islam-cleric-bangladesh/1/708745.html like you did on my prior answer :)

Comment: @pericles316 Look, Indian government fakes a lot of things. I can prove some of them to be untrue but when it comes to investigations, they often fabricate evidence to keep the public cool. If they don't lie about some things, then riots will start. Lie is better than riots.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin-So Najibullah Zazi the Afghan-American was also a fake planted by the Indian government and his accusation of planning suicide bombings on the New York City Subway system is also untrue?

Comment: @pericles316 your first link is dead. And most of the things said on the second link is true but it also has many "...." in the quotes. The thing is, he is a salafi preachers who gets money from the Saudi Government (Ally of US). His primary role is preaching and he doesn't have any political affiliations. The speech they cite about him is an old clip of early 2000s when "liberators" where leveling down cities populated with Sunni Muslims. Many Muslim scholars made a lot of distasteful statements then. Why is he punished for it now? And how does that count as evidence of him inciting terror?

Comment: @pericles316 And what he said is perfectly protected under India's speech laws. He is prosecuted with Zero evidence while the ruling party is vocally converting Muslims and Christians with their money. And his organization does spend money in the conversion process. In some states in India, you need the permission of the state to change religion. This is put in place to keep Hindus from converting to other religions. It requires a lot of money to get the permission from the state (lawyer, fees etc). His organization provides lawyers for new converts. I don't see how that's illegal...

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Your question was whether or not he was paying people. Motivations and ethics don't seem to be part of the problem. This answer addresses the question of whether he paid people, whether it is illegal is another question (and maybe not one we can answer).

Comment: @LioElbammalf The answer is quoting a report that is speculative. The allegations aren't proven yet.

Comment: @Mohammad Sure, but your question was whether he was giving people money to convert. You seem to have accepted that he was but are now questioning whether it is illegal. I'm​ not saying you've not got reason to question that but it should be as a new question rather than debated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firstpost](http://www.firstpost.com/india/mumbai-police-submits-zakir-naik-report-all-set-to-book-preacher-under-uapa-2945934.html), Mumbai police has made allegations of paying to convert against Zakir. But they aren't proven yet.

> The Mumbai Police has recommended that the state book Islamic preacher Zakir Naik under the Unlawful Activities Prevention Act (UAPA) and ban his Islamic Research Foundation (IRF). In a 72-page report on the investigation conducted into Naik's alleged terror links submitted to the home department, the Mumbai Police alleged that Naik had used IRF for 'unlawful activities'.